# Document not updated in findOneAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a post route that receives data from a PUT request in an express app that aims to update a mongoose document based on submitted form input. The "Base" model is `Profile`, and I have two [discriminator](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) models `Helper` and `Finder` that conditionally add fields to the `Profile` schema (see below for details).

Thus, `req.body.profile` will contain different fields depending on the discriminator it's associated with, but will always contain the fields (`username`, `email` `city`, `accountType`) present in the "base" model, `Profile`.

Before I send my PUT request, an example of a document in `Profile` looks like this:

```
{ jobTitle: '',
  lastPosition: '',
  email: '',
  city: '',
  accountType: 'helper',
  _id: 5c77883d8db04c921db5f635,
  username: 'here2help',
  __v: 0 }
```

---

This looks good to me, and suggests that the model is being created as I want (with base fields from `Profile`, and those associated with the `Helper` model - see below for models).

My POST route then looks like this:

```
router.put("/profile/:id", middleware.checkProfileOwnership, function(req, res){

    console.log(req.body.profile);

    Profile.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.profile, function(err, updatedProfile){

        if(err){
            console.log(err.message);
            res.redirect("/profile");
        } else {
            console.log(updatedProfile);
            res.redirect("/profile/" + req.params.id);
        }

    });
});
```

The information I receive from the form (`console.log(req.body.profile)`) is what I expect to see:

```
{ accountType: 'helper',
  username: 'here2help',
  email: 'helpingU@me.com',
  city: 'New York',
  jobTitle: 'CEO',
  lastPosition: 'sales rep'}
```

However, after updating the document with `req.body.profile` in `Profile.findOneAndUpdate()`, I do not see my returned document updated:

`console.log(updatedProfile)`

```
{ jobTitle: '',
  lastPosition: '',
  email: 'helpingu@me.com',
  city: 'New York',
  accountType: 'helper',
  _id: 5c77883d8db04c921db5f635,
  username: 'here2help',
  __v: 0 }
```

So, the fields that are defined in my 'Base' model (ie those defined in `ProfileSchema` - see below) are being updated (e.g. `city`), but those that are in my discriminators are not - see below.

The updated information is clearly present in `req`, but is not propagated to the `Profile` model - **How can this be?**

I've also tried using `findByIdAndUpdate` but I get the same result.

Here are the Schemas I'm defining:

**Profile** - my "base" schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    username: String,
    complete: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    email: { type: String, default: "" },
    city: { type: String, default: "" }
}, { discriminatorKey: 'accountType' });

profileSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Profile", profileSchema);
```

**Finder**

```
var Profile = require('./profile');

var Finder = Profile.discriminator('finder', new mongoose.Schema({
    position: { type: String, default: "" },
    skills: Array
}));

module.exports = mongoose.model("Finder");
```

**Helper**

```
var Profile = require('./profile');

var Helper = Profile.discriminator('helper', new mongoose.Schema({
    jobTitle: { type: String, default: "" },
    lastPosition: { type: String, default: "" }
}));

module.exports = mongoose.model("Helper");
```

This is my first attempt at using [discriminators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) in mongoose, so it's more than possible that I am setting them up incorrectly, and that this is the root of the problem.

Please let me know if this is unclear, or I need to add more information.

Comment: Is there any special reason you need to code the MongoDB call yourself? In normal circumstances, just calling `model.save()` should do the job for you.

Comment: @VinceBowdren. No. I'm new to mongoose and using `Model.findOneAndUpdate()` was the most common way I've seen for achieving what I'm trying to do: 1. Create one base model that includes different fields depending on the `discriminatorKey`. 2. Use this model to generate a form (only show fields in model), and 3. update model from form input.

Comment: @VinceBowdren If this is a bad way of achieving this then I would be happy to change it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**It matters what schema you use to query database**

Discriminators build the mongo queries based on the object you use. For instance, If you enable debugging on mongo using `mongoose.set('debug', true)` and  run Profile.findOneAndUpdate() you should see something like:

```
Mongoose: profiles.findAndModify({
  _id: ObjectId("5c78519e61f4b69da677a87a")
}, [], {
  '$set': {
    email: 'finder@me.com',
    city: 'New York',
    accountType: 'helper',
    username: 'User NAme', __v: 0 } }, { new: true, upsert: false, remove: false, projection: {} })
```

Notice it uses only the fields defined in Profile schema.

If you use Helper, you would get something like:

```
profiles.findAndModify({
  accountType: 'helper',
  _id: ObjectId("5c78519e61f4b69da677a87a")
}, [], {
  '$set': {
    jobTitle: 'CTO',
    email: 'finder@me.com',
    city: 'New York',
    accountType: 'helper ', 
    username: 'User Name', __v: 0 } }, { new: true, upsert: false, remove: false, projection: {} })
```

Notice it adds the discriminator field in the filter criteria, this is  [documented](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html):

> Discriminator models are special; they attach the discriminator key to queries. In other words, find(), count(), aggregate(), etc. are smart enough to account for discriminators.

So what you need to do when updating is to use the discriminator field in order to know which Schema to use when calling update statement:

```
app.put("/profile/:id", function(req, res){
console.log(req.body);

if(ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {

  switch(req.body.accountType) {
    case 'helper':
    schema = Helper;
    break;
    case 'finder':
    schema = Finder;
    break;
    default:
    schema = Profile;
  }      

  schema.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $set : req.body }, { new: true, upsert: false, remove: {}, fields: {} }, function(err, updatedProfile){
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
          res.json(err);
      } else {
          console.log(updatedProfile);
          res.json(updatedProfile);
      }

  });
} else {
  res.json({ error: "Invalid ObjectId"});
} });
```

Notice, above is not necessary when creating a new document, in that scenario mongoose is able to determine which discriminator to use.

**You cannot update discriminator field**

Above behavior has a side effect, you cannot update the discriminator field because it will not find the record. In this scenario, you would need to access the collection directly and update the document, as well as define what would happen with the fields that belong to the other discriminator.

```
db.profile.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, { $set : req.body }, { new: true, upsert: false, remove: {}, fields: {} }, function(err, updatedProfile){
              if(err) {
                res.json(err);
              } else {
                console.log(updatedProfile);
                res.json(updatedProfile);      
              }
          });
```

Comment: This is very helpful, and looks to be working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Please add **option** in findOneAndUpdate - **{ new: true }**;

Answer (score 0):

In Moongose `findOneAndUpdate()` Method have four parameters
like

```
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options, callback) // executes
```

And you need to execute like this

```
var query = { name: 'borne' };
Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, { name: 'jason bourne' }, options, callback)
```

or even

```
// is sent as
Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $set: { name: 'jason bourne' }}, options, callback)
```

This helps prevent accidentally overwriting your document with `{ name: 'jason bourne' }.`